# Navigation Component (RecyclerView)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-navigation

I am currently practicing android and came up with one part that is not very clear to me.  I'm using Android Jetpack ... I have RecycleView, and I want to send a data model to another snippet when I click on it.  I use a navigation component.

Now, I have seen that it is best to share the data via SharedViewModel, but since I have ReciclerView, it is not recommended to insert SharedViewModel ... what is the best way to send data to another fragment?

i also know that uploading large models is not recommended through arg (navigation component)

PS: I want when I click on a reciclerView that has a Name and Address to open a new snippet where I can edit those fields

Answer (score 0):

`what is the best way to send data to another fragment?`

> Often you will want one Fragment to communicate with another, for
>   example to change the content based on a user event. All
>   Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done either through a shared
>   ViewModel or through the associated Activity. Two Fragments should
>   never communicate directly.

This is from the official documentation of Android:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating